# Should I upgrade from 2.3.5p1 to 2.4.4 or later

Tags: magento2, version-upgrade

I have a Magento 2.3.5-p1 site under development but I recently read that this version is EOS in a few months. I was wondering if I should request the platform to be updated to the latest version to ensure the best support. My problem right now is that the site in question has a few modules installed, that are also outdated and I worry they might not work correctly or worse.

Should I request they upgrade to the latest version or is it not worth it yet?

Many thanks and have a great day

Answer (score 0):

1. Use latest version of Magento is always preferable, because of many reason like new features, many bug fixes and etc.
2. Yes, third party extension may be not compatible with latest magento version, but you will get updated version from the vendor where you purchase.